# Съехала верстка в блоке Репутация в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

В профиле съехала верстка в блоке Репутация на закладке Активность:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверено в Opera 34.0 и IE 10.

Comment: Что-то обновили и поломалось. У меня тоже так в Яндекс-браузере.

Comment: OS X, FF 43, Chrome 47, Opera 33, Safari 9.0.2 – везде нормально отображается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin уже поправили, ага. Вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: @andreycha ого, как оперативно. )

Comment: Хотя, это же на всей сети, не только у нас был баг.

Answer (score 2):

Ширина вроде лишняя:

```
.user-show-new .user-rep-chart-summary {
    width: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
```